# JDK 9 jlink is giving Error: --output must be specified

Tags: java, java-9, jlink

I am new to JDK 9 and trying to use jlink to generate a runtime for a simple app.

I have the following module descriptors

```
module reader{

        // no "requires" entries implies no dependency on other modules

        // other modules can access org.reader package
        // all other packages are implicitly unavailable

        exports org.reader;
    }
```

and

```
module decoder {

    // depends on reader module
    requires reader;

    // exposes com.decoder package to modules which require decoder module
    // all other packages in decoder module are implicitly unavailable to other modules
    exports com.decoder;
}
```

I defined a couple of simple classes called Reader.java and Decoder.java, and am able compile and run them using the following steps.

(1) Download and unzip JDK and JRE 9.0.4 to a test directory

(2) Create the following directory structure inside the test directory.

```
/moduleExamples/readerDecoderExample/src/main/java
/moduleExamples/readerDecoderExample/src/main/java/reader
/moduleExamples/readerDecoderExample/src/main/java/decoder
```

(3) Add reader module-info.java, org/reader/Reader.java to reader directory. Add decoder module-info.java, com/decoder/Decoder .java to decoder directory.

(4)  Navigate to test/moduleExamples/readerDecoderExample directory, run the following commands

export JAVA_HOME=test/jdk9.0.4
mkdir mods
export MODULE_PATH=test/moduleExamples/readerDecoderExample/mods

(5) Compile reader and decoder modules

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac -d mods --module-source-path src/main/java/ $(find src/main/java -name "*.java")
```

(6) Run the Decoder class

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java --module-path mods -m decoder/com.decoder.Decoder input.txt
```

(7) mkdir mlibs

(8)  Package modules into jars using the following commands.

```
    ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar --create --file mlibs/reader@1.0.jar --module-version=1.0 -C mods/reader .

${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar --create --file mlibs/decoder.jar --main-class=com.decoder.Decoder -C mods/decoder .
```

(9) At the end of step (8), I have a mlibs dir as shown below

```
readerDecoderExample/mlibs/decoder.jar
readerDecoderExample/mlibs/reader@1.0.jar
```

(10) When I try to build a JRE with the following command

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink --module-path ${JAVA_HOME}/jmods;mlibs/reader@1.0.jar --add-modules reader@1.0 --output out
```

I get the following error.

Error: --output must be specified

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure, you are trying `--add-modules reader@1.0` and not simply `reader`? versions are not required just for your information.

Comment: I re-packaged the modules so that I now have no version
    readerDecoderExample/mlibs/decoder.jar
    readerDecoderExample/mlibs/reader.jar                                          
and re-ran jlink as follows.                                                 
    ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink --module-path ${JAVA_HOME}/jmods;mlibs  --add-modules reader,decoder --output out
I am still getting the same error.

Comment: How about `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink --module-path ${JAVA_HOME}/jmods:mlibs --add-modules reader,decoder --output `? Also, what operating system are you using? Please verify your delimiters accordingly.

Comment: Which operating system is still? If Linux or macOS then you use colon, not a semi-colon, in the module path. If you use semi-colon then it it will truncate your command (this is a shell issue, not a jlink issue).

Comment: I was running the command in a GIT bash shell on Windows. I ran      ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink -v --module-path ${JAVA_HOME}/jmods:libs --add-modules decoder --output imageFromLibs  and this gave me the following message   "Error: Illegal char <:> at index 32: /c/GIT/JDK9/test/jdk9.0.4//jmods:libs".    I skipped to a DOS command prompt and ran                                %JAVA_HOME%/bin/jlink -v --module-path %JAVA_HOME%/jmods;libs --add-modules decoder --output imageFromLibs                                                                                 This worked, thank you for your input!

Comment: @AlanBateman comment helped me. I used ; with mac & it failed with the output must be specified. Changing it to : (colon) fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem on gitbash when I was doing a demo at work. I had tried it previously on a mac and the `${JAVA_HOME}/jmods;mlibs/reader@1.0.jar` works fine, just changing `:` to `;` when moving to PC.

The error seemed to be around the jmods so I just removed it and it worked fine - not sure how or why, this approach doesn't work on the mac.

The following should work:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink --module-path mlibs/reader@1.0.jar --add-modules reader@1.0 --output out
```